# Why do I get a type error in flutter while using DropdownButton with selectedItemBuilder and hint?

Tags: flutter

While using the selectedBuilder and hint simultaneously I get the following error :

> **type 'DefaultTextStyle' is not a subtype of type 'Text' of 'value'**

The following is the code snippet I use in my code :

```
final Map<String, String> _items = [
    {
      'name': "India",
      'code': "+91",
    },
  ];
Map<String, String> _seletedValue;

DropdownButtonFormField(
                      selectedItemBuilder: (_) {
                        return _items
                            .map(
                              (country) => Text(
                                "${country['name']} (${country['code']})",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList();
                      },
                      dropdownColor: Color(0xFF4C4F89),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      items: _items
                          .map(
                            (country) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(
                                "${country['name']} (${country['code']})",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              value: country,
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _seletedValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                      hint: Text('Select your country'),
                    )
```

Can someone suggest some corrections to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to cast the list items to widget

```
selectedItemBuilder: (_) {
            return _items
                .map<Widget>(           // Casting
                  (country) => Text(
                    "${country['name']} (${country['code']})",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList();
          },
```

Hope that works!
**Reference:** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html